# Truncating a TMemo in Lazarus by removing first X lines

Tags: arrays, lazarus, fpc

I'm using a TMemo in Lazarus to display a rolling log, but I want to limit it to the last 500 entries.

What I'd like to do is (in pseudo-code):

```
if (log_TMemo.Lines.Count > 500) then
   log_TMemo.Lines := log_TMemo[LinesCount - 500 to LinesCount];
```

TMemo contains TStrings `TMemo.Lines`, so I guess a want a way to copy a subset of the TStrings array.

Is there a way to do this, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it uses iteration, [this](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,27073.msg167168.html#msg167168) response in the Lazarus forums works perfectly.

```
while log_TMemo.Lines.Count > 500 do
    log_TMemo.Lines.Delete(0);
```